# How do I hook local account creation in windows?

Tags: windows, active-directory, hook

I'm trying to hook local account creation and block it if needed (I'm building a small security tool which will even block administrators from messing around with configurations).

I've figured out that I must inject to LSASS, But I'm not really sure what is the exact function I need to detour.
Currently I'm testing on XP SP3, But I'm looking for a solution that will work on every windows from XP to 8 .

I've tried to detour SAM's functions SamrCreateUserInDomain but it hasn't been called when I've created a local user using lusrmgr.msc.
I've also tried LsarCreateAccount. But it hasn't been called as well.

I figured that I probably need to hook some Active Directory function but I'm not sure which one is it.

Any help?

Comment: Active Directory is strictly a server technology.  It isn't involved in creating local account on client OS versions such as XP.  Are you certain your detour is actually taking effect?  What hooking technology are you using?  (My understanding is that some hooking technologies only work for Win32 applications and not executive components such as LSASS.)  Perhaps a global hook on NetUserAdd would be more effective?

Comment: I'm injecting a DLL and detouring the code itself (The very same method worked perfectly on "services.exe" for example). And the DLL was injected successfully into "LSASS" (Shown on ProcXP, and writes logs to debug output). Sadly, Blocking NetUserAdd won't be good enough because some of the techniques to create users might not call this function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem.
I hooked the wrong function.

I should have hooked SAM's SamrCreateUser2InDomain, not SamrCreateUserInDomain.

Fixing that, and everything is working perfectly.